# VB.Net How to show line # in RichTextBox?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I was wondering if it's possible to show the line number you're on in a rich text box in Visual Basic/Studio. I've seen some for C# but not for .vb forms. If possible, thanks!

Comment: it has nothing to do with C# vs VB.net. The concept should still be the same.

Comment: If you have seen code to do it in C#, then **yes, it is possible** in VB.

Comment: [RichTextBox.GetLineFromCharIndex()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.getlinefromcharindex.aspx)

Comment: Here is a good link: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18294/LineNumbers-for-the-RichTextBox